# Asp.net "background service" listening to MSMQ not working after IIS site is stopped/started

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5, msmq

We've implemented a "background service" in our Asp.Net web app that receives messages from MSMQ at random intervals without requiring an HTTP request to start up the application. We auto start this web app using a [serviceAutoStartProvider](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx).

Everyhing works when IIS initially starts up, the server is rebooted and so on, we receive messages just fine. *BUT* if we just stop the site in IIS (not touching the application or app pool), the application stops receiving MSMQ messages. And when we start the web site again, the serviceAutoStartProvider is not called again, so our app does not start listening to MSMQ messages again!

If we issue a HTTP request against the web app after the IIS site has been stopped and started again, it starts listening to MSMQ messages again.

1. Shouldn't our "background service" web app continue to listen to MSMQ messages even if the IIS site is stopped? It won't get any requests, but I think it should continue to run.
2. What exactly happens in an Asp.Net application/app pool when the IIS site is stopped? Any events fired that we can hook up to? The app pool claims to be "started" in IIS manager, but code is not running in it.
3. Why isn't our serviceAutoStartProvider called when the site is started again? I believe it is "by design", since the application isn't really stopped. But the applications isn't running, either, has to be waken up by an actual HTTP request.

Comment: Here is a potential fix: http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2009/10/14/now-available-the-iis-7-5-application-warm-up-module.aspx

Comment: I agree, and we looked at that, but the Application Warm-Up has been pulled by Microsoft, see: http://forums.iis.net/t/1176740.aspx. They have not announced why or if a replacement is coming, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the IIS Web App shuts down (eg. due to no new HTTP(S) requests for the timeout time) the .NET app domain (within the app pool worker process) completely closes and unloads. This includes all background  threads, including those used by the .NET thread pool.

A Web App can be configured with a longer (or no) timeout, then background worker threads could continue to process work.

But better would be to either run such workers in a specialist service process managed completely separately.

Or, even better, use IIS application hosting with WCF to create the MSMQ listener. I understand in this case the integration of Windows Process Activation Services with IIS would restart the Web App if a new message arrived after it had been shutdown.

Comment: Ahh, but the point here is that it does not look like the *IIS Web App* is actually shut down. Only the site in IIS is stopped. I gather this mainly from the fact that the serviceAutoStartProvider is *not* called when I start the site again.

Yes, I am also beginning to think that a WCF Service with the MSMQ listener hosted in IIS 7.5 with AppFabric is the only way to get this working reliably with IIS.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer, as it is what we ended up doing. :-)
(The last part: "use IIS application hosting with WCF to create the MSMQ listener. I understand in this case the integration of Windows Process Activation Services with IIS would restart the Web App if a new message arrived after it had been shutdown.")

Answer (score 0):

I would host the MSMQ listenner in a windows service. Why couple it to IIS?

**UPDATE**

Actually what I mean is why couple the MSMQ and ASPNET in the same app pool?

Comment: We want this running in IIS because of ease of deployment. We have a good setup for deploying web apps to our pretty complex environment, using Web Deploy and Web Farm Framework.

Comment: To be honest ease of deployment would not factor massively into my reckoning here. I see a clear case of creating a needless dependency.

Comment: The dependency on IIS for hosting a "service"? I agree, to some extent. But we lack a decent and cheap application server on Windows. The only thing from Microsoft is IIS with AppFabric Hosting, not very impressive yet. How do you recommend deploying, hosting and monitoring X number of instances of an MSMQ listener on 10+ machines, for 3 different environments (configurations)?

Comment: OK sorry I did not really mean the dependency between IIS and the service. I don't have a good answer to that. But why host both in the same app pool? This introduces the kind of service-lifecycle-coupling effect you are experiencing.

Comment: x years later @hugh if deploying a Windows service wasn't such a monumental pain in the ass that also requires developers to depend on their networking team every time a bug is fixed I could've supported your point of view. +1 to poster's first comment to on this answer.

Comment: I agree on the point of ease of deployment, but would like to note to everyone here that MSDeploy can be used to stop, uninstall, package, push, install and start windows services just as well as it can web applications. It does, however, require you have some experience in the scripting department, as well as basic .NET tools usage (namely installutil.exe) but if you're in charge of deployment certainly you fall into this category (or you might acquire some additional talent in your company if you don't, it can't hurt.)

In the right light, this problem amounts to added cost to your employer.

Comment: @DavidGrenier not sure what you mean that deploying a windows service is a "monumental pain in the ass" - these are not exactly complex deployments and can usually be accomplished with an xcopy command and about 2 lines of powershell.

Comment: @hugh yes, if as a developer you have domain credentials with permissions to do that. We don't have such requirements when deploying a website to IIS via filesystem but granted others might.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use "Application Initialization" feature of IIS8 (and IIS7.5), more information including version availability and usage documentation can be found at:

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization

This replaces "Application Warm-Up Module" which is no longer supported, and provides us with proper control over component/service initialization in an "always running" scenario.